# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" in jquery.js. Email signup form with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to build a simple email signup, and I came across this tutorial which seemed to be exactly what I wanted to do (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-a-sleek-ajax-signup-form/). I don't have much programming knowledge, so this was my best bet at getting something up and running. I followed the tutorial, but unfortunately, I'm having some problems with it.

My problem is when I try to submit an email address, I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in jquery.js, on line 565. 
When I expand the error in Dev Tools, it shows:

```
jQuery.extend.parseJSON                jquery.js:565
$.ajax.success                         common.js:36
jQuery.Callbacks.fire                  jquery.js:1046
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith         jquery.js:1164
done                                   jquery.js:7399
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback     jquery.js:8180
```

As I said, I'm a rookie with this, so I greatly appreciate any help. I've been researching for a while, but haven't found any issue the same as mine. Some were similar, but I couldn't fix the issue with any of the solutions I came across.

This is the form code:

```
<form id="newsletter-signup" action="?action=signup" method="post">
    <fieldset>
    <label for="signup-email">Sign up for email offers, news & events:</label>
    <input type="text" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" />
    <input type="submit" id="signup-button" value="Sign Me Up!" />
    <p id="signup-response"></p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

This is the signup JS:

```
/* SIGNUP */
$('#newsletter-signup').submit(function(){

    //check the form is not currently submitting
    if($(this).data('formstatus') !== 'submitting'){

        //setup variables
        var form = $(this),
            formData = form.serialize(),
            formUrl = form.attr('action'),
            formMethod = form.attr('method'), 
            responseMsg = $('#signup-response');

        //add status data to form
        form.data('formstatus','submitting');

        //show response message - waiting
        responseMsg.hide()
                   .addClass('response-waiting')
                   .text('Please Wait...')
                   .fadeIn(200);

        //send data to server for validation
        $.ajax({
            url: formUrl,
            type: formMethod,
            data: formData,
            success:function(data){

                //setup variables
                var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data), 
                    klass = '';

                //response conditional
                switch(responseData.status){
                    case 'error':
                        klass = 'response-error';
                    break;
                    case 'success':
                        klass = 'response-success';
                    break;  
                }

                //show reponse message
                responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('response-waiting')
                           .addClass(klass)
                           .text(responseData.message)
                           .fadeIn(200,function(){
                               //set timeout to hide response message
                               setTimeout(function(){
                                   responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                                       $(this).removeClass(klass);
                                       form.data('formstatus','idle');
                                   });
                               },3000)
                            });
                });
            }
        });
    }

    //prevent form from submitting
    return false;
});
```

And this is the PHP:

```
<?php
//email signup ajax call
if($_GET['action'] == 'signup'){

mysql_connect('host','user','password');  
mysql_select_db('table');

//sanitize data
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['signup-email']);

//validate email address - check if input was empty
if(empty($email)){
    $status = "error";
    $message = "You did not enter an email address!";
}
else if(!preg_match('/^[^\W][a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $email)){ //validate email address - check if is a valid email address
        $status = "error";
        $message = "You have entered an invalid email address!";
}
else {
    $existingSignup = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM signups WHERE signup_email_address='$email'");   
    if(mysql_num_rows($existingSignup) < 1){

        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $time = date('H:i:s');

        $insertSignup = mysql_query("INSERT INTO signups (signup_email_address, signup_date, signup_time) VALUES ('$email','$date','$time')");
        if($insertSignup){ //if insert is successful
            $status = "success";
            $message = "You have been signed up!";  
        }
        else { //if insert fails
            $status = "error";
            $message = "Ooops, Theres been a technical error!"; 
        }
    }
    else { //if already signed up
        $status = "error";
        $message = "This email address has already been registered!";
    }
}

//return json response
$data = array(
    'status' => $status,
    'message' => $message
);

echo json_encode($data);
exit;
}
?>
```

Thanks!

UPDATE: Shad - I inserted that code right after 'success:function(data){' Is that correct? After doing that, when trying to submit an email address, I get this in the console, pointing to the line with the newly added code:

```
Failed:  
SyntaxError
arguments: Array[1]
get message: function getter() { [native code] }
get stack: function getter() { [native code] }
set message: function setter() { [native code] }
set stack: function setter() { [native code] }
type: "unexpected_token"
__proto__: Error
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in <b>/homepages/37/d403623864/htdocs/_php/launch_notify.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
{"status":"error","message":"Ooops, Theres been a technical error!"}
```

Screenshot of Dev Tools with that error. Let me know if you need to see any of the lines expanded or anything: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwnBr.png

**UPDATE #2:** Using the code provided by satoshi, I think I made a little progress on figuring out the issue, but I still haven't solved it. I think I narrowed it down to a MySQL connection issue. I tried this code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("[DB]","[USER]","[PASS]") 
or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
mysql_select_db("signups") 
or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to Database";
?>
```

And the response I get is:

```
Connected to MySQL
Access denied for user '[USER]'@'%' to database 'signups'
```

I've tried a bunch of things, but can't figure it out. My host is 1&1, and I created the table through there using PHPMyAdmin. I've tried different tables, all get the same issue. Here's  a screenshot showing the table in PHPMyAdmin: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe0Fm.png

Thanks again for all the help so far everyone. I appreciate it.

Comment: What does the php page response look like?

Comment: First thing i would recommend is catching the error =) (in a useful way:)
`try {responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data)} catch (e) {console.log('Failed: ', e, data);}`

Comment: Shad - I updated the original post. Thanks.

Comment: I know it might sound really stupid, but are you sure that you specified the correct login/db details?

Comment: Yeah, positive. I even tried different databases, and had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP file is warning you because `$existingSignup` is not a valid resource. This is because your SQL query is invalid. For this reason, because PHP is outputting something unexpected, the page doesn't return a valid JSON response.

Please verify that your `mysql_query(...)` call returns a valid resource before calling `mysql_num_rows(...)`, like this:

```
$existingSignup = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM signups WHERE signup_email_address='$email'");
if($existingSignup !== FALSE)
{
    if(mysql_num_rows($existingSignup) < 1){
        // ...
    }
    else { //if already signed up
        $status = "error";
        $message = "This email address has already been registered!";
    }
}
else {
    $status = "error";
    $message = mysql_error();
}
```

Edit: please note that the query is syntactically correct, I guess you face the problem because you didn't set up the DB table correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I updated the original post in response to this.